# How to load local font in webpack angular-seed/universal

Tags: angular, webpack

I have case that I need to load local font into my [ng-seed/universal](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal.git),
I'm just newbie here and I need some suggestion to make it work.

I have tried to add bellow config on my `webpack.config.js`, but it seems to be not working :)

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
```

And here is my font face in my `sass` file that called to my custom font

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CustomFont';
    src: url('./assets/fonts/CustomFont.eot');
    src: url('./assets/fonts/CustomFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./assets/fonts/CustomFont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./assets/fonts/CustomFont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When I hit `npm run` on dev mode I got an error `Error: Path variable [chunkhash] not implemented in this context: assets/CustomFont.[chunkhash].eot`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you to import globallly for the whole app?

Comment: Yes I do want import globally for the font :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the rule and if you are intending to apply this font to the whole app, put this inside styles.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CustomFont';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/CustomFont.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/CustomFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/CustomFont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/CustomFont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

*no. before /assets

Comment: wow it's working, I don't know it will be that simple to fixed the problem, I almost looking it for an hour, I thought it was problem on my webpack setting, you just save my day thanks....:)

Comment: Thanks Again, I'm sorry I can not up vote your answer, I have not enough point to up vote you :)