# how to generate webfont from SVG icons in angular

Tags: angular, webpack, webfonts

I have some SVG icons, but I want to use them as font in my project. Anybody knows how can I import my icons as font in an angular project?

There is an answer in this URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfonts-generator , but I don't know in which file of my project I should use it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add font-awesome to Angular 2 + CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project)

Comment: i don't want font awesome. i want to use some custom font i draw them.

Comment: OK, so what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465888/custom-font-import-in-angular4 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803868/how-to-load-local-font-in-webpack-angular-seed-universal ?